# Swift String behaving strangely with escaping a single quote

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Essentially I need a `String` in this example to hold the value `"This is John\\'s"`. No matter how much XCode gymnastics I try to employ here, I just can't get it to behave how I want. I would just leave it as an `NSString` but the API I am providing this to requires a `String`, and casting it back breaks it. See below, I'm fresh out of ideas.

```
(lldb) po "This is John's"
"This is John\'s"

(lldb) po "This is John\'s"
"This is John\'s"

(lldb) po "This is John\\'s"
"This is John\\\'s"

(lldb) po "This is John\\\'s"
"This is John\\\'s"

(lldb) po "This is John\\\\'s"
"This is John\\\\\'s"

(lldb) po "This is John\\\\'s" as NSString
This is John\\'s

(lldb) po ("This is John\\\\'s" as NSString) as String
"This is John\\\\\'s"
```

Comment: And what if you put it in a `UILabel`? I think that's because you are debugging the value, and XCode/Apple/Debugguer might print differently special char in strings to show the user that its present.

Comment: I thought so too, but the API I am hitting is returning an error code explicitly saying I passed in an "incomplete string"

Comment: Use  `print(string)` *in your program* (not in the debugger console) to verify wha the string actually contains. As @Larme says, the debugger adds additional escape characters.

Comment: You can also use `print(_)` in the debugger. `po print("john's")` or `expr print("john's")`.